# Creating array from object function using map

Tags: perl, dictionary

I have an array of [`HTML::Element`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Element)s obtained from [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::TreeBuilder) and `HTML::Element->find` and I need to assign their `as_text` value to some other variables. I know I can really easily do

```
my ($var1, $var2) = ($arr[0]->as_text, $arr[1]->as_text);
```

but I was hoping I could use `map` instead just to make the code a bit more readable as there are at least 8 elements in the array. I'm really new to Perl so I'm not quite sure what to do.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're well versed in [`perldoc -f map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) it's pretty clear:

```
my @as_texts = map { $_->as_text } @arr;
```

Works as well if you want to assign to a list of scalars:

```
my($var1, $var2, $var3, ...) = map { $_->as_text } @arr;
```

But of course the array version is better for an unknown number of elements.

Comment: This is a major issue of personal preference but I prefer to use the EXPR form of `map` when the transform is simple enough: `map $_->as_text, @arr`.

Comment: @hobbs - I often do to, but I wasn't sure if $_->as_text would work as expected in that case. I know `map chr, @arr` works, but I didn't know if method calls could be made to work the same way. I suppose the only way to find out is to test it, but in this specific case I personally prefer to use brackets.

Comment: @hobbs `map EXPR,LIST` is also faster than `map BLOCK LIST` but I am a sucker for the latter.

Comment: @Chris: most stuff works, as long as you keep track of the arity of the functions you're calling and use parens for the "listop" ones. But it's always good to have a "when in doubt" rule. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that, if you just want to map the first two elements of `@arr`:

```
my($var1, $var2) = map { $_->as_text } @arr;
```

will invoke `$_->as_text` for all elements of `@arr`. In that case, use an array slice to avoid unnecessary calls:

```
my($var1, $var2) = map { $_->as_text } @arr[0 .. 1];
```

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = 'a' .. 'z';
my $count;
my ($x, $y) = map { $count++; ord } @arr;

print "$x\t$y\t$count\n";

$count = 0;
($x, $y) = map { $count++; uc } @arr[0 .. 1];

print "$x\t$y\t$count\n";
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> jk
97      98      26
A       B       2
```

`ord` was called for each element of `@arr` whereas `uc` was called for only the elements we were interested in.